# Stop Multiple returns from Server after query with Apollo and Angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript, apollo

Bellow is an example on code I am using to submit data to a server and the return I receive and save

```
this.apollo.mutate( { mutation: XXXXXXXX, variables: { instance_string: X, 
accesstoken: X } })
.subscribe({
   next: (data: any ) => {
     console.log("data returned from Server", data); 
     // This data can be sent from the Server in a loop on occassion
     this.SaveData(data);
   },
   error: (err) => {
     this.presentToastFail(err);
   }
 });
```

On occasion the Server returns the data in a loop.  I have no control of the Server and it appears this will be a reoccurring bug for quite a while.  Is there a way that I can can insure the next: only runs once and ignores the Loop of data returns the Server can send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to use two pipeable operators like `take(), filter()`:

```
.pipe(
  filter(resp => resp !== undefined && resp !== null),
  take(1) // <--- It will only take one successful valid response
)
.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: This one worked well and stopped the Server from sending a loop

Answer (score 1):

It looks like u can also use `takeuntil`
[Takeuntil reference document](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil)

```
    const example = evenSource.pipe(
  //also give me the current even number count for display
  withLatestFrom(evenNumberCount),
  map(([val, count]) => `Even number (${count}) : ${val}`),
  //when five even numbers have been emitted, complete source observable
  takeUntil(1)//this will take 1st response
);
```